# How to sum up these sine functions?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

What is the solution of this kind of exercise $A=\sin2a+\sin4a+\ldots+\sin10a$

I have already tried to multiply with $2\cos \frac a2$ to solve this.

Comment: Multiply both sides $\sin a$

Comment: Yes still can not

Comment: Can not devide it cuz it's going to be different which at the end is cosa/sina can not

Comment: Want a solution ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to obtain it.

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin (2ka)&=\Im\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{2ika}\right)\\\\
&=\Im\left( e^{2ia}\frac{e^{2ina}-1}{e^{2ia}-1}\right)\\\\
&=\Im\left( e^{2ia}\frac{e^{ina}\left(e^{ina}-e^{-ina}\right)}{e^{ia}\left(e^{ia}-e^{-ia}\right)}\right)\\\\
&=\Im\left( e^{2ia}\frac{e^{ina}\left(2i\sin(na)\right)}{e^{ia}\left(2i\sin(a)\right)}\right)\\\\
&=\Im\left( e^{i(n+1)a}\frac{\sin(na)}{\sin(a)}\right)\\\\
&=\Im\left( \left(\cos ((n+1)a)+i\sin ((n+1)a)\right)\frac{\sin(na)}{\sin(a)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(na)}{\sin(a)}\sin ((n+1)a).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can u solve it as grade 11 answer? Actually this is higher that my ability

Comment: Please, can you tell me what specific point you don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok I get it I was confused thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome!